# Concern about Closed-as-Duplicate Questions Hiding Information

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

A user brought up an issue in comments. He doesn't seem to feel he can discuss the issue here, so I thought I'd bring it up on his behalf.

In reference to "[SOAP vs REST (differences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences)", a question I voted to close a year ago, but which is still open, he said:

> on SO everything is a duplicate, even if it's not. This is definitely not a duplicate because of the way the questions were answered. If you hid this question from view information would be lost. The guy on the other post even came back (3 years later) to put a bounty on the post; meaning he saw this one and didn't get the "in-depth" answer he is specifically requesting.

It continued:

> @OKGimmeMoney: I voted to close this as a dupe over a year ago, yet it is now open. Closing doesn't hide the question in any case.
>
> @JohnSaunders Excuse me if I seem a bit harsh It's just that I've experienced and seen many useful questions that, IMO, inappropriately marked as a duplicate/too board/off topic/etc.. And the result is a a blockade in the way of the information flow; I like to see information flow. :) –  OKGimmeMoney
>
> @OKGimmeMoney: you are mistaken. Duplicate questions, in general, remain on the site. And the information flow is improved if we don't have thousands of copies of the same question diffusing the information which should actually be concentrated in one place. –  John Saunders
>
> @JohnSaunders i stand by what I said –  OKGimmeMoney
>
> @OKGimmeMoney: if you feel you have an issue, you should discuss it on Meta Stack Overflow. –  John Saunders
>
> @JohnSaunders Ok, I'll be more frank. the high rep users of this site are extremely pretentious. Care to argue with that? I already know what you're going to say. And to head off your next spiel: I already posted about what I'm talking about here where you're directing me and it was DELETED by a mod; after met with a wave of negativity. Whatever you guys are doing is not the best action you could take; and if it's an ego/power trip - I don't even know who you are - am I supposed to bow down to you and give you godly programmer status or something (because that's how it comes across). –  OKGimmeMoney
>
> @OKGimmeMoney: did you post that today? Can you send me a link? I'll look into it. We "high-rep users" are not in collusion with the moderators. If you feel there's an issue, then I would like it to be discussed. –  John Saunders
>
> @JohnSaunders Too late. I'm already gone. Just deliver the change and if it's pushed to my attention again I'll make this my primary site again. I'm already using other sites for my questions and I assure you I'm am far more productive because of it. So give me your passive aggressive "I wish you luck" "You're welcome to use another site" `<insert best wishes here>`. –  OKGimmeMoney
>
> @OKGimmeMoney: ok, I'll do it myself and post the link here. –  John Saunders
>
> @OKGimmeMoney: See "[Concern about Closed-as-Duplicate Questions Hiding Information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295061/concern-about-closed-as-duplicate-questions-hiding-information)". Please feel free to correct me and to reply. –  John Saunders

Comment: Questions closed as duplicates still exist on the site and can still be found via searching. What exactly is there to discuss here?

Comment: That guy has a tantrum and quits every six months or so.